# Why are expired cookies not removed in Firefox v117.0.1 using nookies package in Next.js?

Tags: firefox, next.js, cookies

I'm working on a Next.js project that uses the [nookies] package to set and delete cookies. I have two cookies in my project that have an expire time. I set the cookies using nookies.set(ctx, name, value, options), where options includes the maxAge property. I expect the cookies to be removed from the browser when they expire, but they are not. This only happens in Firefox v117.0.1, other browsers work fine. Here is some sample code of how I set the cookies after login:

```
export const setUaaCookie = (access: string, refresh?: string): void => {
  const accessExpires = GetTokenExpireTime(access);
  const refreshExpires = GetTokenExpireTime(refresh);

  setCookie('access_token', access, {
    expires: accessExpires,
    path: '/',
    domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
  });
  setCookie('refresh_token', refresh, {
    expires: refreshExpires,
    path: '/',
    domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
  });
  request.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${access}`);
};
```

And these cookies should be automatically deleted from the browser after they expire.
I have a custom AuthProvider component that wraps around my app and handles the authentication logic. Here is the code of my AuthProvider component:

```
  const authenticate = (): void => {
    // get browser cookies
    const cookies = parseCookies();
    const hasToken = cookies.refresh_token;
    let isPrivateRoute = true;

    const publicRoutes = [
      '/account/login',
      '/account/otp-login',
      '/account/signup',
      '/account/forget-password',
    ];

    // current route is a public route or a private route
    if (
      publicRoutes.find(item => router.asPath.includes(item)) ||
      router.asPath === '/'
    )
      isPrivateRoute = false;

    if (isPrivateRoute && !hasToken) {
      goToLoginPage();
      setLoading(true);
      return;
    }

    if (!isPrivateRoute && hasToken) {
      const next = router.query.next || '/market-summary';
      router.push(next.toString());
      setLoading(true);
      return;
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    authenticate();
  }, [router]);
```

After I log out automatically, when I log in again in the `AuthProvider` file, the token logs are still undefiend, and after logging in, we are redirected to the login page again. And then we can log in a second time. In fact, we have to log in twice to enter the site.

This issue was recently created and did not exist in older versions of Firefox

Why is this happening? How can I fix this issue with nookies package in Next.js and Firefox v117.0.1? How can I make sure that expired or deleted cookies are removed from the browser and do not interfere with my auto logout feature?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue with Firefox and auth tokens. I don't know exactly why Firefox doesn't remove expired cookies but what I saw is that even if you update it, Firefox keep in mind that the cookie is expired. This issue appeared with the Total Cookie Protection mechanism, there is an [open bug in Firefox about that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=576347) ( old one but set back to open now )

#### The issue

- First login => set cookies `access_token` and `refresh_token`
- Wait for cookie expires => cookie is expired but still present in Firefox storage.
- Login => replace cookies `access_token` and `refresh_token`
- First request => retrieve the cookie `access_token` that is considered as expired for Firefox so the cookie is not sent in your request.
- The response is 401 / 403, then the logout is triggered ( cookie deleted )
- Login => set new cookies `access_token` and `refresh_token`
- First request => retrieve the cookie `access_token` that is live
- Response is 20X, everything is fine

#### Fixes

- Use cookie set by server directly with httpOnly: true (can be hard to implement depending on your architecture, not tried)
- Switch to localStorage (easier but not the recommended option, it's still exposed to XSS attacks, same as cookie storage used here)
- Usage of in memory token or sessionStorage (but having issue with opening new tab / reload page)

Here is an implementation of localStorage that you can add :

```
const AUTH_KEY = 'auth';
type AuthStorage = {
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  expires: Date;
};

function getAuthCredential(): AuthStorage | undefined {
    const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_KEY);
    if (!token) {
      return undefined
    }
    const parsedToken = JSON.parse(token);
    // This replace the expire of token
    if (new Date(parsedToken.expires) > new Date()) {
      return parsedToken;
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }

function setAuthCredential(): void {
    setAuthCredential({
      accessToken: auth.accessToken,
      refreshToken: auth.refreshToken,
      expires: GetTokenExpireTime(refresh),
    });
}

const hasToken = getAuthCredential();
```

About security (XSS / CSRF) the current cookie is used in JS so a XSS attack can get it, the usage of localStorage can reduce the risk of CSRF attack (depending on your cookie SameSite parameter), but keep in mind that this  solution is not the best one for this issue.

#### Related links

[OWASP - Token Storage on Client Side](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html#token-storage-on-client-side)
[auth0 - Token Storage](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage)

I hope it will help you,